# jQuery Mobile type="button" or type="submit" not working (UI)

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile `type="submit"` or `type="button"` (UI) inside a `<form>` tag is not working. Same thing replaced by `type="text"` or anything except `type="button"` and `type="submit"` works perfectly.

The code is

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/twitter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header"><h4>Pay</h4></div>

  <div data-role="content">
   <h4>You are about to Pay Nrs <span id="paymentAmount"></span> for <span id="trees"></span> Trees.</h4>

   <form id="paymentForm">
               <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                      <input value="100"       name="amt"   type="hidden">
               </div>
               <div>
                      <input value="Pay" type="button" name="payBtn"/>
               </div>
    </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: JQM typeButton]

## The same code on jsfidlle (without my script and link imports) appears as

 
[image]

Comment: How do you know it is not working? What did you expect to happen? Your data was not submitted?

Comment: I was talking about UI. See the first screenshot. UI is not loaded on local server.

Comment: UI is not loaded after the submit? What I don't understand in your example is are you trying to use jQuery Mobile way of form submitting (because I cant see action and mode attriute in your form) or a classic form submittion?

Comment: No, this is the page where I want to handle `submit` after click on payBtn but sadly `<input value="Pay" type="button" name="payBtn"/>` is cauing UI not being able to load. When I remove `<input value="Pay" type="button" name="payBtn"/>` UI is loaded successfully. <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> the same code to jsfidlle works.

Comment: use `<button type="submit">Pay</button>`

Comment: @Omar `<button type="submit">Pay</button>` doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you show us your jsFiddle example?

Comment: @Gajotres [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/prayagupd/v7Efe/1/)

Comment: Shit. jQuery version was causing error. I updated to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js and it looks working. @Gajotres you can answer it though, I can accept that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery version is causing you the problem.

You should switch to **[jQuery 1.9.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js)** and everything should work just fine.